# Зачем в Java 2 интерфейса: Iterable и Iterator?

Tags: java, ооп

По-моему они только вносят путаницу. Я так понял их роли: Iterable говорит что по объектам класса в принципе можно итерироваться, а Iterator задает сами методы для итерирования. Но по-моему все это отлично смотрелось бы в одном интерфейсе. Который и объявлял бы класс итерируемым и одновременно задавал бы методы для итерирования.

Comment: Иногда приходится решать задачи, требующие реализации своих итераторов и Iterable. Вот пример не совсем стандартной работы с коллекциями, здесь нужно обойти две коллекции в определённом порядке. Если бы это была одна сущность, всё было бы заметно сложнее, пришлось бы писать свой класс коллекции. Но благодаря разделению этих интерфейсов, мы можем гибко комбинировать. http://blog.shamanland.com/2016/03/composite-iterator-ru.html

Answer (score 13):

Можно было бы об этом задуматься, если предполагаемое соответствие `Iterable` и его `Iterator` было **"один к одному"**. Но дело обстоит иначе: `Iterable` может в некий момент обходиться несколькими `Iterator` сразу (возможно, ещё и в разных thread'ах!). То есть, это интерфейсы, представляющие две разных сущности: **коллекцию** и **обход коллекции**.

Уже поэтому стоит их разделить, поскольку в противном случае для нескольких параллельных обходов коллекция должна быть **всегда завёрнута в итератор** и иметь два вида копирования (для итератора и для коллекции), а тут уже просматривается явное нарушение [SRP (Single Responsibility Principle, **принципа единственной обязанности**)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Answer (score 3):

Один - тот кто ездит. Это Iterator
Другой - тот на ком ездят. Это Iterable

Первый не возможен без Второго. Второй возможен без первого, но бесполезен.

А на самом деле Iterable - всего лишь способ задать стандартный механизм извлечения итератора. Он не является таким уж важным в деле итерации. Он не нужен совсем.
Например у List есть ещё listIterator, к которому Iterable вообще никакого отношения не имеет. но тем не менее это настоящий итератор и даже упруженный дополнительными возможностями.

Answer (score 0):

> ... все это отлично смотрелось бы в одном интерфейсе

Не смотрелось бы.

`Iterator` — это *интерфейс*. То есть мы можем вызвать метод какого-то класса, передать ему итератор и как бы сказать: «вот тебе некая последовательность, пробегись-ка по ней и сделай ряд действий».

Благодаря абстрактности итератор может быть вообще не привязан ни к какой коллекции, а самостоятельно генерировать значения на лету!

Причём эти действия, связанные с последовательным проходом по элементам, одинаковы для любого типа контейнера.

Но даже если считать, что любой итератор завязан на своём контейнере, то всё равно получается нехорошо. Итератор — это вспомогательная сущность, состояние которой надо хранить. Плюс, как правильно [заметил @D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490068/208074), итератор даже уровне восприятия является отдельной сущностью.